# Matlab: how to stop command window printing?

Tags: matlab

Sometimes I accidentally print a say 5000x5000 matrix, which takes a long time. How can I stop the command window from printing?

I am using Matlab R2015a on a Mac. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Windows machine, it's Ctrl + C. This stops executing code as well as printing. I assume it is comparable on a Mac: Ctrl + C.

Comment: @ rayryeng: thx... typing on the phone is always a pain.. (on a German keyboard crtl is strg)

Comment: It's still Ctrl + C on a Mac.  I've corrected that, as well as several typos.

Answer (score 2):

On a mac it's 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Sorry for the short and not very appealing answer.

Answer (score 1):

clc to clear the command window, ctrl+c to stop execution and ; at the end of the line you don't want to print will suppress the command window output.